# awk command I don't understand

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script written by someone else and there is something I don't understand in it
I have a function in this script :

```
_service_description_prefix(){
    echo "select xxxxxxxxx" | _mysql_execute | awk -F";" '
    function _print(AAAA, BBBB){
        if ( AAAA == "" ) { next };
        DESCR=AAAA";"ALERT ;
        exit
    }
    /.*/ { DESCR="" ; AAAA="" ;
        if ( $2 ~ "^L24/7" ) { ALERT="yes" } else { ALERT="no" };
         }
    ( $3 == "ZZ" ){
        xxxxxx
    }
    ----- There are a lot more here -----
    ( $3 == "YY" ){
        xxxxxx
    }
    /.*/ { AAAA="ee" ; ALERT="no" ;
    }
    '
}
```

What I don't understand is the meaning of /.*/
And all the ($3 == xx) which seem to be behave like an if condition but I don't have the "if" !
Is that some syntax I don't know ?

Thx for your help !
amans

Comment: The whole content of that string is an awk command, not "bash code". Please update your title to something more useful to future readers. Also I would recommend learning some basic awk.

Comment: @TomFenech - I see that it's in the awk. And I know some basic and even a bit more I think in awk. But I still don't understand the meaning of what I said previously, even after I searched on internet.

Comment: awk uses blocks of code to deal with a line in a file. Blocks are surrounded with squirrelly brackets `{}`. Conditions can be put in front of blocks. You'll see normal conditions like `$3=="ZZ"` meaning if the third field is equal to "YY", then execute the block. And you'll see regex like `/.*/` which means "any character except a line break repeated any number of times" which is peculiar. I'm honestly not sure why it's included here as awk is already dealing with the file line by line.

Comment: `/.*/` matches everything so it may as well be removed.

Comment: @TomFenech Thank you for saying that. I hadn't run into it before and I couldn't figure out if it was superfluous or I was losing my mind

Comment: btw whoever wrote that script doesn't know awk very well so treat it with a pinch of salt, it may not always do what you hope it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `/.*/` and `$3 == "YY"` are basic awk syntax.  You can find detailed descriptions in the [awk man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html), but here's a quick summary.

An `awk` program consists of multiple statements of the general form:

```
pattern { action }
```

A *pattern* can be pretty much any expression; if it evaluates to `true`, then `awk` will execute the *action*.  The pattern `/.*/` is a [regular expression](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) that matches "any character, any number of times".  So:

```
/.*/ { action }
```

Will match any line that contains zero or more characters. In other words, it will always execute *action*.  In fact, it is equivalent to:

```
{action}
```

The expression is `$3 == "YY"` is a simple boolean expression that checks if field number 3 equals "YY".  By default, `awk` splits input on whitespace, so given the following input:

```
AA MM YY ZZ
AA MM XX ZZ
```

The first line would match `$3 == "YY"` and the second would not.

Comment: Thx for the explanation ! I didn't know we could write it like this in the awk.